# timeoffset in whole minutes in c#

Tags: c#

I have a method that calculates the number of minutes between two times. Something like this:

```
DateTime UserLocalTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ConvertToUserTime(UserTimezoneID);

double TheOffset = (UserLocalTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes;

return TheOffset.ToString();
```

The problem is that it's returning something like 119.83723 because it's calculating minutes AND seconds and such.

How can I fix this? I'm afraid sometimes it'll also return 120.11233 so rounding might not totally help either.

Thanks for your suggestions.

*Update1: (int)(Math.Round((UserLocalTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes)); returns 119.*

Update2: I tried this, it looks like it works but will fail when the offset is weird (sometimes it might be 5:30 and the answer should be 330 minutes)

```
int TheOffset = (int)(Math.Round((UserLocalTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalHours));
TheOffset = TheOffset * 60;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you want to get only the minutes and nothing else? Just use `Minutes` instead of `TotalMinutes`.
- Do you want to get the total number of minutes, but not any measure beneath it? Use `(int)TotalMinutes`. It'll round down.

> I'm afraid sometimes it'll also return 120.11233 so rounding might not totally help either.

Can you clarify? Rounding `120.11233` will result in `120`... I think that's what you want, right?

Comment: Funny: when I change to .Minutes, it returns 59

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, `Minutes` is *just* the minutes; hours, etc. are excluded. I wasn't really sure which of these answered your question, so I added them both.

Comment: ok, so if I parse to an int, it now returns 119 instead of the expected 120.

Comment: (int)(Math.Round((UserLocalTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMinutes)); returns 119.

Comment: @frenchie: So... are you rounding to the nearest half-hour, or something?

Comment: @minitech: yes, nearest half-hour would be a good description.

Comment: @frenchie: Oh. Well then: `Math.Round(TotalHours / 2) * 120`

Answer (score 0):

You have can use:

- [Math.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get the nearest integer
- [Math.Floor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/e0b5f0xb%28v=vs.95%29) to get the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number.
- [Math.Ceiling()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.95%29) to get the smallest integral value greater than or equal to the specified number.
- 119,895 -> Floor= 119, Ceiling = 120, Round = 120
- 119,175 -> Floor= 119, Ceiling = 120, Round = 119

Apply the desired function to your TheOffset.

If you need Ceiling or Floor, you should probably invert the function used if negative or positive offset.

So, you decide what you want to get.

Comment: No, what I mean is that with 120.232424, I'll get floor = 120, ceiling  = 121 and round = 120. So in other words there's no function that'll return what I need in case the number comes out either above or below 120.